# Partial query with Where statement using Elasticssearch 7 java api

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-7

I am using the following to search. It is working fine. But it is returning the results when complete word match is found.  But I want results with a partial query (minimum 3 characters match incomplete word). Another check should be , I have a field `campus` in my document. Which has values like `campus: "Bradford"` , `campus:"Oxford"`, `campus:"Harvard"` etc. I want that my query should return the document whose `campus` should be `Bradford or Oxford` and `Nel` will be available in the rest of the entire document.

```java
    RestHighLevelClient client;

        QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("Nel");
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name");
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

If we map with the SQL statement, as we used `where campus='Bradford' OR  campus='Oxford'`.

In the document, I have "Nelson Mandela II"

Currently, it is working if I write `Nelson` as query but I need it to work with query `Nel`.

Comment: @opster-elasticsearch-ninja

Comment: Isn't this wild card query ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Answer (score 2):

There basically two possible ways to achieve the use-case you are looking for.

### Solution 1: Using wildcard query

Assuming that you have two fields

- `name` of type `text`
- `campus` of type `text`

Below is how your java code would be:

```
private static void wildcardQuery(RestHighLevelClient client, SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Wildcard Query");
        
        MatchQueryBuilder campusClause_1 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("campus", "oxford");
        MatchQueryBuilder campusClause_2 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("campus", "bradford");      

        //Using wildcard query
        WildcardQueryBuilder nameClause = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("name", "nel*");
        
        //Main Query
        BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                                .must(nameClause)
                                                .should(campusClause_1)
                                                .should(campusClause_2)
                                                .minimumShouldMatch(1);

        sourceBuilder.query(query);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();

        //specify your index name in the below parameter
        searchRequest.indices("my_wildcard_index");
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Note that if the fields of the above were of `keyword` type and you need exact match for case sensitivity, you'd need the below code:

```
TermQueryBuilder campusClause_2 = QueryBuilders.termQuery("campus", "Bradford");
```

### Solution 2. Using Edge Ngram tokenizer (Preferred Solution)

For this you would need to make use of [Edge Ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer.

Below is how your mapping would be:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": "lowercase",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "campus": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Nelson Mandela",
  "campus": "Bradford"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "name": "Nel Chaz",
  "campus": "Oxford"
}
```

### Query DSL

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "nel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "campus": "bradford"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "campus": "oxford"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

### Java Code:

```
private static void boolMatchQuery(RestHighLevelClient client, SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Bool Query");
        
        MatchQueryBuilder campusClause_1 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("campus", "oxford");
        MatchQueryBuilder campusClause_2 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("campus", "bradford");      

        //Plain old match query would suffice here
        MatchQueryBuilder nameClause = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "nel");
        
        BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                                .must(nameClause)
                                                .should(campusClause_1)
                                                .should(campusClause_2)
                                                .minimumShouldMatch(1);

        sourceBuilder.query(query);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.indices("my_index");
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits());
}
```

Note how I've just made use of match query for the name field. I'd suggest you read a bit about what [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html), [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html), [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html#analyzer-anatomy-tokenizer) and [edge-ngram tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) are about.

In the console, you should be able to see the total hits of the document.

Similarly you can also make use of other query types for e.g. `Term query` in the above solutions if you are looking for exact match for `keyword` field etc.

### Updated Answer:

Personally I do not recommend `Solution 1` as it would be lot of computational power wastage for a single field itself, let alone for multiple fields.

In order to do multi-field sub-string matches, the best way to do that would be to make use of a concept called as [`copy-to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) and then make use of Edge N-Gram tokenizer for that field.

So what does this Edge N-Gram tokenizer do really? Put it simply, based on `min-gram` and `max-gram` it would simply break down your tokens for e.g.

Zeppelin into `Zep, Zepp, Zeppe, Zeppel, Zeppeli, Zeppelin` and thereby insert these values in the inverted index of that field. Not if you just execute a very simple `match` query, it would return that document as your inverted index would have that substring.

And about [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) field:

> The `copy_to` parameter allows you to copy the values of multiple fields
> into a group field, which can then be queried as a single field.

Using copy_to field, we have the below mapping for the two fields `campus` and `name`.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": "lowercase",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "search_string"            <---- Note this
      },
      "campus": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "search_string"            <---- Note this
      },
      "search_string": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"             <---- Note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice in the above mapping, how I've made use of the Edge N-gram specific analyzer only to `search_string`. Note that this consumes disk space as a result you may want to take a step back and make sure that you do not use this analyzer for all the fields but again it depends on the use-case that you have.

**Sample Document:**

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "campus": "Cambridge University",
  "name": "Ramanujan"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "search_string": "ram"
    }
  }
}
```

And that would give you the Java Code as simple as below:

```
private static void boolMatchQuery(RestHighLevelClient client, SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Bool Query");

        MatchQueryBuilder searchClause = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("search_string", "ram");

        //Feel free to add multiple clauses
        BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                                .must(searchClause);

        sourceBuilder.query(query);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.indices("my_index");
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Was the above answer useful? Did it help?

Comment: Its helpful sir. Thanks for this. If I need to search from the complete document instead of a single `name` then how could I change my query?

Comment: @Lily please check the `Updated Answer` section in the above solution. And let me know if that helps!